# Form based authentication for Fediz STS

Tags: authentication, saml

I have configured Fediz IDP and STS succcessfully on my server and also deployed the client "SimpleWebApp" on my local machine. I am able to get the response from STS. Now i want to convert the existing username/password popup into a login page. Can you please let me know the modifications i need to make to achieve this functionality.

Thanks